# How to kill someone when a score reaches 0

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a minigame that's in a space station. Everyone gets a certain amount of oxygen using scoreboards.

I am stuck on how I can kill a player when they reach 0 oxygen. I have tried

```
/testfor @a["scoreboard name"=0]
```

but this does not seem to work. **How can I kill the player when they reach 0 oxygen?**

I am using Minecraft version 1.7.10.

Comment: You were on the right track, just some syntax problems. Simply put `score_` in front of the "scoreboard name". I recommend replacing the `/testfor` command with a `/kill` command if you're simply using it to kill players, for simplicity's sake. Therefore your command would become `/kill @a[score_<scoreboard name>=0]` For future reference, `/testfor` is mostly useless. If you find yourself using it, i highly suggest checking everything and seeing if a `/scoreboard` command would suit your needs better (it almost always will).

Answer (score 2):

if you're still on 1.7 (the other answer only works on 1.8+), then try:

```
/effect @a[score_O2remaining=0] 20 5 100
```

to give those players a strong Wither effect for 5 seconds.

Comment: Wither is effect 20, I edited your answer accordingly. Good first answer, welcome to Arqade! Take the [tour] and check out the [help] if you have any questions regarding the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try this looped on a fill clock:

```
/kill @a[score_NAME_min=0,score_NAME=0]
```

This should kill all players that have a score of zero. All you need to do after that is set the killed players oxygen score back to 10 so that they don't keep getting killed.

Comment: The target selector to check for a maximum score is `score_NAME`, rather than `score_NAME_max`.

Comment: I don't think so, @MrLemon. The way scoreboard are working is kind of weird. You can't test for an exact value with `score_WHATEVER`. You need to append `_max` to it, if I remember correctly

Comment: @Seblor: You are incorrect.  `score_NAME` matches everyone who has a score equal to or less than the value, `score_NAME_min` matches everyone who has a score that's at least the value.  Combine the two to match everyone who has a score that is exactly equal to the value.  I do wish that we had `score_NAME`, `score_NAME_min`, and `score_NAME_max`.

Comment: The `_0` won't do anything useful either.

Comment: Then what would I use if I wanted to test for an exact score? @sharpturn

Comment: `@a [score_name_min=0,score_name=0]` is the only way to do it in vanilla.

Comment: Note that you also cannot have spaces anywhere within the selector parameters, including between the selector and square bracket: `@a[score_NAME_min=0,score_NAME=0]`

Comment: So since selector parameters are a part of the general selector, they need to be connected to it. This is useful info that I will be using in the future.